# how to use print statement when you have more than 8000 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure and the code looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Gen_Proc] 
(@ID INT )
AS
Begin

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#procedure') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #procedure

DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Script VARCHAR(MAX),
@DB VARCHAR(100),
@Schema VARCHAR(100),
@Proc_Name VARCHAR(max),
@BR CHAR(2)

SET @BR = CHAR(10)+ CHAR(13)

SET NOCOUNT ON 

SELECT @Name= [Procedure_Name] FROM dbo.datsource 
WHERE [ID] = @ID

SELECT  @Proc_Name = PARSENAME(@Name, 1) ,
        @Schema = PARSENAME(@Name, 2) ,
        @DB = PARSENAME(@Name, 3)


CREATE TABLE #procedure ( script VARCHAR(MAX) )

EXEC('INSERT INTO #procedure(script)
SELECT definition FROM '+@DB+'.sys.all_sql_modules sq
WHERE sq.object_id = (SELECT object_id FROM '+@DB+'.sys.objects
WHERE type = ''P'' AND name = '''+@Proc_Name+''' ) ')


SET @Script = ' Use ' +@BR  +@DB + @BR+ '  Go' +@BR

SELECT  @Script = @Script+script
FROM    #procedure


DECLARE @pos INT =7500

SELECT  @pos=CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@script,@pos)

PRINT SUBSTRING(@Script,1,@Pos)

DECLARE @Counter INT
SET @Counter = 0
DECLARE @TotalPrints INT
SET @TotalPrints = ( LEN(@script) / 8000 ) 
WHILE @Counter < @TotalPrints 
    BEGIN   

        SET @Counter = @Counter + 1

        PRINT SUBSTRING(@script,@pos+1,7500)
        SET @pos = @pos+7500

        SELECT  @pos=CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@script,@pos)

    END 
END
```

Basically what the procedure is doing it just prints the procedure code. But the problem I am facing is when I am printing it i am loosing some characters in between.

Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to print ?

Why you don't do a select with the script, put it in xml if you want to see everything.

```
Select Convert(xml, @script)
```

EDIT :

between you don't need to do +1

```
PRINT SUBSTRING(@script,@pos,7500)
```

Comment: I want to print it i dont want it in the result set

Comment: I understand, not sure it's possible then

Comment: since Print has limitation of 8000 characters I am trying to loop it. i was doing substring based on the line break but something seems to wrong which is truncating some text

Comment: Nope the problem is in the loop. The first print statement is printing from 1 to 7500 characters thats why i set @pos to 7500.